# Can we transform LWE symmetric encryption scheme into a commitment scheme?

Tags: symmetric, commitments, lwe

In the LWE symmetric encryption scheme, a ciphertext encrypting a message $\mu \in \{0,1\}$ under the secret key $\mathbf{s} \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n$ is $(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}=\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{s}+e+\frac{q}{2}\mu)$, where $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n$ is a uniformly sampled vector and $e \in \mathbb{Z}_q$ is a noise.

My question:
Using the ciphertext as a commitment and $(\mu, \mathbf s)$ as revealed values, can we transform the LWE symmetric encryption scheme into a commitment scheme?
While it clearly satisfies a hiding property under the LWE assumption, its binding property is not obvious.